# proper usage of "half this, half that"

Tags: adverbs

One of the ways to describe a mixed feeling is to use a pattern with half. For example:

> I stood there half frightened, half exasperated.

and I was wondering if it's common to use as long as a sentence in this pattern and for example say:

> I stood there, half making sure everybody is enjoying themselves, half
> avoiding to be getting in the way.

is it a proper way to describe mixed situations like this?

Comment: in your sentence, those aren't feelings, those are actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You've replaced two phrases headed by past participles ("frightened" and "exasperated") with two phrases headed by present participles ("making" and "avoiding"). However, your sentence has some other issues; I'd write it this way:

> I stood there, half making sure everybody was enjoying themselves, half staying out of the way of people.

By the way, this construction is not unique to "half"; you can use other words, too. For example:

> I stood there, partly frightened, partly exasperated.